# Configuring the backBarButtonItem of a View Controller's Navigation Item in a Storyboard

Tags: interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, uistoryboard

It's easy enough to drag and drop bar button items onto a view controller's navigation bar in a storyboard in Interface Builder. In this way, you can set the `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem` outlets of the view controller's navigation item. But there's also a `backBarButtonItem` outlet, and it's not obvious at all how to set it. How can I set a custom back bar button item using Interface Builder?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Select the view controller whose navigation items you want to change. The black bar displaying the identity of the view controller changes to an iconified tray of its referenced objects.
- Drag and drop a bar button item from the object library onto the tray.

[image: Storyboard view of a navigation controller and subordinate table view controller]

- Right-click on the view controller's navigation item in the main object tray on the left-hand side. Wire up the newly added button as the navigation item's `backBarButtonItem` outlet.

[image: Interface Builder screenshot illustrating how to wire up the back bar button outlet]

- Select the bar button and configure it in any way you choose with the Attributes Inspector.

[image: Screenshot of the attributes inspector in Interface Builder showing options for the back bar button item]

Comment: My navigation item already has a `backBarButtonItem` wired (since it is the destination of a push segue) and it is unchangeable. There seems to be no way to actually change the title of the back button -- setting the "Back Button" field in the Attribute Inspector has no effect.

Comment: I would encourage you to create a separate question for this if you're seeking a solution and you find the idea of doing this programmatically to be distasteful. Unfortunately, yours is a situation I've not encountered yet.

Comment: @wcochran - this happened to me as well.  It's a small oversight in Xcode, the workaround is to choose UIBarButtonItem in the object library, then drag it over the left bar button item of the UINavigationItem.  You'll see a blue rectangle appear, then it will set it and you can configure it as usual.

Answer (score 16):

As @wcochran noted above, when working with viewControllers pushed onto a navigationController's stack, the backBarButtonItem outlet is already wired and can't be changed. Furthermore, selecting the child VC's navigationItem and changing the Back Button text in IB doesn't do what you would expect.

Now you might think that replacing the child VC's backBarButtonItem would solve the problem, but it doesn't. Confusingly, if you want to set the title of the back button of a child VC, you have to set the back button title of its *parent* (!), like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated // in the parent VC!
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

This won't do anything on the parent VC. In fact, if the parent is the navigationController's RootViewController, there won't be a back button at all. But the child will inherit (or pick up) the back button you've created.

This only applies to the immediate child VC, so if you want to maintain the label down through the navigationController's stack you need to set it on each parent.

*Thanks to @wiliz in #iphonedev for explaining this to me.*

Comment: I am coming back from long while to iOS development and despite all advances we need to do hacks such as this one. Things have not changed much from iOS 3.1.2. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @AdamBlock noted above, you have to set things right in the parent VC.

He shows how to do this programmatically. It is also possible to do this in interface builder.

- Select the parent VC
- Select the navigation Item
- Open the Attributes inspector
- Set the title for the Back Button.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, you can change the Navigation Item back button's title.

Programmatically, you can set a custom back button in your view controller's viewDidLoad method. In this example we set the button's image to an image named "customImage.png":

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

    // Set custom image here
    backButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customImage.png"];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. See my answer for how to configure the other button properties within Interface Builder.

Comment: @warrenm provide link also. so user can get this answer directly.